# What does it mean VCS has encountered unamed generate blocks?

Tags: verilog

**My Code:**

```
generate
 if(some_condition) begin
    assign A=~AB;
 end else begin 
    assign A=AB;
 end
endgenerate
```

I get an error saying VCS has encountered unnamed generate blocks. And it points to the lines where i have the assign statements. Is there a multiple drive issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
generate

 if(some_condition) begin : generate_block_1
    assign A=~AB;
 end else begin  : generate_block_1
    assign A=AB;
 end

endgenerate
```

In several revisions, Verilog has changed the way generates are handled. In older versions a generate item or keyword by itself did not introduce a new scope so the designer had to add a named block to do this. I don't think this is 'real' error in 1364-2001 since you are not declaring an identifier inside the generate but it is good practice to name generate blocks.

1364-2005 and SystemVerilog fixes this by stating any unnamed generate block are called genblk##, although you should still name them anyway.